# variable was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus

I'm not very familiar with BAT files but I have a file that runs a sqlplus query, returns the row count, and if it is greater than 0, run another bat file. I feel like I'm almost there but I keep getting this error:

%%a was unexpected at this time

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'sqlplus USER/PASS@OMP1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL'
) do set rowcount=%%a
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
c:\SQLTRIGGERS\VoiceBlkAutoationBAT.bat
)
```

when I run the above, I get this as a reponse:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (    
%%a was unexpected at this time
 'sqlplus USER/PASS@OMP1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL'
''sqlplus' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
) do set rowcount=%%a
if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
More? c:\SQLTRIGGERS\VoiceBlkAutoationBAT.bat
More?
```

when I run this:

```
sqlplus user/pass@P1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL
```

I do get an integer value back too

Answer (score 2):

why is there such a gap between the `SET` and `rowcount?`

In itself, it's of no matter - but I suspect that you have them on separate lines.

The `set rowcount=%%a` must all be on the same physical line as the `do` - and the `do` must be on the same physical line as the closing parenthesis after the `in`

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'sqlplus user/pass@P1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL'
) do set rowcount=%%a
```

if perfectly legitimate.

---

As a .bat file:

```
:: @echo off
echo starting SQLPLUS
sqlplus USER/PASS@OMP1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL
echo finished SQLPLUS

for /f "delims=" %%a in (
 'sqlplus USER/PASS@OMP1 @VoiceBlockTrig.SQL'
) do ECHO(+%%a+&set /A rowcount=%%a

ECHO rowcount=+%rowcount%+

if %ROWCOUNT% GTR 0 (
c:\SQLTRIGGERS\VoiceBlkAutoationBAT.bat
)

PAUSE
```

This is the batch that appears to be close to what you'd need to run.

The changes are:

- added `ECHO(+%%a+` in the `FOR` loop.
- - The open-parenthesis following the ECHO is simply a character that has been found to be better than SPACE to separate the `ECHO` from the text-to-be-echoed
- - The `+` before and after the %%a simply delimits the string with an
    obvious character so that the presence of SPACES can be more easily observed.
- `SET` changed to `SET /A` which interprets the value assigned as a
  numeric-string, which should overcome any stray spaces in the
  assignment.
- Added `ECHO` of the rowcount within delimiters for visibility
- Added  PAUSE to stop the procedure from closing before you have a chance to see the results.

Comment : Probably the `"delims="` is not required, but we'll get to that when the problems are defeated.

Comment: Your report that the script required TWO `ENTER`s could mean that the `SQLPLUS` is asking for input. If so, `'ECHO.^|sqlplus...` may alleviate the problem.

If SQLPLUS is a BATCH, a different approach would need to be made.

Further changes to attempt to solve puzzing result:

- Double-colon before @echo off - double-colon is often used as a
  comment. The object is to show the lines being executed.
- Added the SQLPLUS command independently - to observe results.
- Added two ECHO lines to display progress.

Certainly very odd....

Comment: The `More?` prompts and the position of the `%%a was unexpected at this time` are telling. You need to use a text editor to put the commands into a batch file called `virtuallyanythingyoulike.bat` you then run the file from the prompt by issuing the command `viruallyanythingyoulike`. Within a batch file, the metavariable `%%a` requires two `%` signs. If run from the prompt, you need to use but one. MUCH easier to use a file and edit it rather than perpetually retyping the commands and invoking all those spellinge errors.

Comment: ok, I took the code above, pasted it in a txt file and saved it as a .bat. Double clicked it to open but all I get is a blank CMD screen.....if I hit enter twice in it it closes then.

Comment: ok...tried your new code but all I get is a blank CMD screen still...now I can hit enter repeatedly and nothing seems to happen.